# Allow larger file upload size to certain users in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Carrierwave audio to upload audio files. Up until now I've had it set at a certain size for all users, but I just implemented premium subscriptions. I would like to have a way to let subscribed users upload larger files. How would I do this, since you can't access the current_user in the model?

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'

class Track < ApplicationRecord
  include Taggable
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :album, optional: true, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :pseudonym, optional: true
  has_many :favorites, counter_cache: true
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  has_many :events, as: :eventable, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :flags, as: :flaggable, dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :listings
  enum explicit: { standard: 0, explicit: 1 }

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  mount_uploader :audio, AudioUploader
  validates :audio, file_size: { less_than: 15.megabytes }, presence: true
  validates :image, file_size: { less_than: 1.megabytes }, presence: true
  validates :tag_list, presence: true

  attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
  after_update :crop_image

  def crop_image
    image.recreate_versions! if crop_x.present?
  end

  def self.tagged_with(name)
    Tag.find_by_name!(name).tracks
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Track` belongs to `User`, what you can do here is something like this.

```
class Track < ApplicationRecord
  # other code
  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
  mount_uploader :audio, AudioUploader
  validates :audio, file_size: { less_than: audio_file_size_limit }, presence: true

  private

  def audio_file_size_limit
    return 15.megabytes unless user.premium_subscriber?

    30.megabytes
  end
  # other code
end
```

Comment: I get an error now from this. `undefined local variable or method `audio_file_size_limit'` I don't know why it says that, you have it clearly defined. I also tried taking the method out of private and it still gives me that error.

Comment: Quite bizarre, it requires a number or a proc instead of a method. @ddonche
https://github.com/musaffa/file_validators/blob/b25ec342d1fa38829350d15423ee0a5ea9bbb2a6/README.md#file-size-validator